# Decompiler unmanaged code exe?

Tags: c++

I have an exe file. I used ILSPY to decompile it to source code that i can edit code. But it show an error

> This file does not contain a managed assembly

Please suggest me how to decompiler it. Thank you so much

Comment: Use a decompiler that decompiles unmanaged (normal) code, instead of one that decompiles .NET code?

Comment: Either give up or prepare for much work.

Comment: Please suggest me some tool can decompiler unmanaged code. Tks you

Comment: Compiled native code doesn't contain the source code and can't really be decompiled. I assume there exist assembly to C/C++ translators, but they will produce hard-to-read stuff.

Comment: @YvesDaoust There are even programs generating C++ from binaries, but as you said, it's *hard* to read. Reading assembly (and manually translating it to C++) is much easier than this ... thing.